# Do I need to create a mock/stub to test this asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, jasmine, angular2-testing

The function I want to test is asynchronous, This function is present in a class.

Do I need to create a mock/stub to test this function?If yes then how to create one?

```
delayedAlert(message: string, time: number, cb){
             return setTimeout(()=>{
                cb(message)},3000)}

//calling this function shows the asynchronous behavior successfully.
```

Comment: Google finds this easily "async test jasmine" https://metabroadcast.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-jasmine

Comment: yes, I saw that article before posting this question. But my question is different I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

A popular library for stubbing a function or an API is [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.4.0/stubs/). The documentation has lots of help around creating a stub, and how to test it. This can then be used in conjunction with something like [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) to run some async tests.